# How to view individual css when using @import in rails asset pipeline in development

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am calling several styelsheets in `application.css.scss` which contain require directive and `@import`

**Current**

```
*= require font
*= require font-awesome
*= require twitter/bootstrap
@import "bourbon";
@import "app_css_that_uses_bourbon_mixins
```

In order to use [bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon) gem (from thoughtbot) , I have to use the @import syntax. However, when i start to use  @import, i am losing out the ability to view individual css files in the development mode. But, when i use `*= require directive`, I am able to view the css files individually in development mode. I believe this properties (of viewing individual, non concatenated files) are derived from   '`config.assets.debug = true`' which is the setting in my app.

Since there are several csss' I am having difficulty in debugging them when sprockets concatenates them, I would like to be able 
1. Be consistent to use `@import` syntax
2. Be able view the individual css files for debugging in the development mode.

**Want**

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "twitter/bootstrap";
@import "app_css_that_uses_bourbon_mixins
.....
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

I would scrap the require and stick with all import and explicitly list each file.

I'm not sure if this is any help, but you can just browse the URL for your individual stylesheets. Let's say for instance I have signin.css.scss - 
I can browse to

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/signin.css
```

This will show the files contents!

I'm going to have a play with my development environment to see if I can get it to list it inside the dev tools.